# How to apply a distinct css class to each value of a field with multiple values?

Tags: theming, entities

In a similar manner to views-row classes, is it possible to add a distinct css class to each value of a field where cardinality is greater than one?

Ideally I am looking for a module that does this.

Comment: I forgot what cardinality is, can u refresh my memory?

Comment: The number of values you can have per-field @NoSssweat

Comment: Could you use pseudo classes like `:nth-child()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: @bloke_zero A friend on twitter has just suggested a similar approach. Perhaps you want to post this as an answer

Comment: @MrPaulDriver, what is being styled?  I ask because If it is `<option>` in a `<select>` it is hard to style the options (browser chrome sets most of that), but if it's <li> elements or divs it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: @bloke_zero styling entity references - node teasers and other entity view modes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach would be to use CSS `:nth-child()` pseudo classes.  Assuming some HTML output like:

```
    <div class="entity-reference-wrapper">
        <div class="entity-reference">
            [CONTENT]
        </div>
        <div class="entity-reference">
            [CONTENT]
        </div>
        <div class="entity-reference">
            [CONTENT]
        </div>
        <div class="entity-reference">
            [CONTENT]
        </div>
    </div><!--/.entity-reference-wrapper -->
```

You can target the 2nd div with css like this:

```
    .entity-reference-wrapper .entity-reference:nth-child(2) {
        color: green;
    }
```

Odd children like this:

```
    .entity-reference-wrapper .entity-reference:nth-child(odd) {
        color: green;
    }
```

There are a lot more options over at CSS tricks here:  https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Comment: I am afraid this might wont work, since I think all the multiple values get displayed as 1 field.

Comment: @No Sssweat I thought the same, but it tested okay.